# Weird flickering with CSS transform + jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've made (with the help of [this tutorial](http://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/docs/cube.html)) a flip-card for a web-project I'm working on. When I was just using images (in the test fase) everything went well, but since I replaced the images with `div`s and filled those with content, I got some weird flickering when the "back"-card was getting displayed:

[image]

You can try it out here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gxxomtrr/)

As you can see, the front-card is visible through the back-card when it's transitioning.

Is there a fix for this problem? I can't go back to images, since the content has to be changeable through a CMS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added a higher `z-index` to the `.front' and it worked.

```
.front {
    z-index: 2;
}
```

[SEE IT HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/gxxomtrr/3/)

Comment: Yep, that's it. Great find!

Answer (score 1):

I reckon you're using Chrome (maybe Safari), this CSS ought to solve it :

```
.eventimage {
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

That's for the image at least...

Comment: Adding a higher  `z-index` does the job, but the `backface-visibility` was a good find!

Answer (score 0):

Translate the .back 1px in the Z dimension:

```
#card .back {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(1px);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(1px);
    -o-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(1px);
    transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(1px);
}
```